# When i trying to fetch data from database to text field , showing error

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

When i trying to fetch data from database to text field in a form, it is showing error "ErrorException in 58276d4d127ecceedfd25e52a10ce5c9c39f20d3.php line 31:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$userID (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\opennGTS\resources\views\user\add.blade.php)".
Actually i am using laravel 5.2. 
my add.blade.php page code is given below.

```
 <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
            <li class="active">View/Edit User</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">View/Edit User Information</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if (count($errors) > 0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('accountAdmin') }}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            @foreach($name as $nam)
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User ID</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="{{ old($name->userID)}}" placeholder="Enter User ID">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Active</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('isActive') }}" name="isActive" >
                                        <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="0">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" placeholder="Enter the description">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactName" value="{{ old('contactName') }}" placeholder="Enter Contact Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Phone</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactPhone" value="{{ old('contactPhone') }}" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Email</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" value="{{ old('contactEmail') }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Notify Email</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="{{ old('notifyEmail') }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Time Zone</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('timeZone') }}" name="timeZone" >
                                        <option value="0">GMT+05:30</option>
                                        <option value="Inactive">xyz</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Authorized Group</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('distanceUnits') }}" name="distanceUnits" >
                                        <option value="0">all</option>
                                        <option value="1">Km</option>
                                        <option value="2">Nm</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Login page</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('firstLoginPageID') }}" name="firstLoginPageID" >
                                        <option value="0">Main Menu</option>
                                        <option value="1">Liter</option>
                                        <option value="2">IG</option>
                                        <option value="3">ft^3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Maximum Access Level</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('maxAccessLevel') }}" name="maxAccessLevel" >
                                        <option value="3">New/Delete</option>
                                        <option value="1">Read/View</option>
                                        <option value="2">Write/Edit</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                        Save
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                @endforeach
                        </form>
```

and my Usercontroller page is

```
class UserController extends Controller
```

{
    public $type = 'User';

```
public function getIndex()
{

    $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
    return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);
}

public function getData()
{

    $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(50);
    return view('user.add')->with('name', $name);
}

public function userInsert()
{
    $postUser = Input::all();
    //insert data into mysql table
    $data =      array('userID'=> $postUser['userID']
    );
    //  echo print_r($data);
    $ck = 0;
    $ck = DB::table('user')->Insert($data);
    //echo "Record Added Successfully!";
    $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
    return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);


}
```

}

Can anyone help me to find out the mistake i had done in my code?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Will the variable is **$name->userID** or **$nam->userID**???? can you check that?

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User ID</label>
             <div class="col-md-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="{{ old($name->userID)}}" placeholder="Enter User ID">
             </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: sorry it is nam->userID, but now am getting new error"Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\opennGTS\resources\views\user\add.blade.php)"

Comment: From your code it seems to me that you are using **getData()** function.now just for sure you have checked your **$name** variable buy **var_dump($name)** or **dd($name)** in your view right?